# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '/Users/dbl/spark/lib_managed/jars' does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I built Spark 1.6 SNAPSHOT from sources with no issues: 
$ mvn3 clean package -DskipTests.

I'm running:
OS X 10.10.5.
Java 1.8
Maven 3.3.3
Spark 1.6 SNAPSHOT
Scala 2.11.7
Zinc 0.3.5.3
Hadoop 3.0 SNAPSHOT

I added the following dependency to my pom.xml (to try to resolve the warning about native libraries):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.netlib-java</groupId>
  <artifactId>netlib</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Environment variables:

```
HADOOP_INSTALL=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/etc/hadoop
HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/native
CLASSPATH=/users/davidlaxer/trunk/core/src/test/java/:/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-dist-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/davidlaxer/clojure/target:/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/lib/native:
SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/davidlaxer/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lib/native
```

When I try to launch spark with: spark-shell I get the following error:

```
./spark-shell
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '/Users/davidlaxer/spark/lib_managed/jars' does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:249)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildClassPath(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildJavaCommand(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:115)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:196)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

I reverted to Spark 1.5 and didn't have the problem:

```
git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git -b branch-1.5
```